# Spring data Jpa save/update not working in rest service

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am faced with a problem which I can not find the solution. I try to update my database from my service rest. With my repository service I manage to access my db and execute the 'find' functions but not the 'save' method. Do you have an idea?

Here is the class in question, after debug, my object is well updated but the save function does not update the bdd.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ControllerVehicleApi {

    @Autowired
    private CourtierRepository courtierRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pack/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String  getPackByNom(@RequestBody Pack1 pack)  {

        Courtier courtier=courtierRepository.findBySiren(pack.getSirenCourtier());

        if(courtier==null){
            return "Pas de courtier dans la base de données";
        }else {
            for (Pack1 p : courtier.getCourtierJson().getPackList()) {
                if (p.getNom().equals(pack.getNom())) {
                    p.setPolicySpecialConditionUUID(pack.getPolicySpecialConditionUUID());

                }
            }
            courtierRepository.saveAndFlush(courtier);
        }
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

thx you :)

Comment: include @Transactional on enclosing the method.

Comment: You need to show your `Database configuration` and your `Repository`?

Comment: Also, what are you doing? curl command for example including the result (stack trace, reply or whatever you see)

Comment: You should create a `@Service` layer so you can write your business logic in there. And there you can use a `@Transaction` method.